# Me.Handle in Module - Alternative?

Tags: vb.net, audio, module, codedom

I am currently programming something but I've hit a small problem, which is:

Using `Me.Handle` in a module that will be used as the source for a CodeDom-Compiler.

I want or rather need to use it in the following procedure:

```
Private Const APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_MUTE As Integer = &H80000
Private Const WM_APPCOMMAND As Integer = &H319
Declare Function SendMessageW Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal Msg As Integer, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr

Private Sub Mute()
    SendMessageW(Me.Handle, WM_APPCOMMAND, Me.Handle, CType(APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_MUTE, IntPtr))
End Sub
```

You get the idea, I want to mute the System-Sound. I am more or less searching for some way of doing
this without using `Me.Handle`, as it is not working in my module for some reason...

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright guys I managed to fix it by doing this:

```
Private frm As New System.Windows.Forms.Form()  
SendMessageW(frm.Handle, WM_APPCOMMAND, frm.Handle, CType(APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_MUTE, IntPtr))
```

That's basically what it does inside of the module, thanks anyways!

Answer (score 3):

SendMessage requires a handle to a form, which you don't have in a module or standard class.

Three options are either to pass in a reference to a form like this:

```
Private Sub Mute(formRef As Form)
    SendMessageW(formRef.Handle, WM_APPCOMMAND, formRef.Handle, CType(APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_MUTE, IntPtr))
End Sub
```

Or use a handle to the first form in the collection:

```
Private Sub Mute()
    SendMessageW(Application.OpenForms(0).Handle, WM_APPCOMMAND, Application.OpenForms(0).Handle, CType(APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_MUTE, IntPtr))
End Sub
```

Or use a reference to the MainWindowHandle:

```
Private Sub Mute()
    SendMessageW(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle, WM_APPCOMMAND, Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainWindowHandle, CType(APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_MUTE, IntPtr))
End Sub
```

Comment: you need to replace the first `Me.Handle` reference as well!

Comment: Yes @Grim well spotted

Comment: No problem!  It's made my boring day at work feel productive, if nothing else!

Comment: Alright so since SendMessage requires a form, is there any other way to mute the system-audio without the library provided by ElektroStudios that doesn't require a form?

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative you could use [Vista Core Audio API](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18520/Vista-Core-Audio-API-Master-Volume-Control)

Example Class I wrote:

```
Public Class MasterVolume

    ''' <summary>
    ''' The device enumerator.
    ''' </summary>
    Private DeviceEnumerator As New CoreAudioApi.MMDeviceEnumerator()

    ''' <summary>
    ''' The default device.
    ''' </summary>
    Private DefaultDevice As CoreAudioApi.MMDevice =
      DeviceEnumerator.GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(CoreAudioApi.EDataFlow.eRender, CoreAudioApi.ERole.eMultimedia)

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Gets or sets the current volume.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <value>The current volume.</value>
    Public Property Volume As Integer
        Get
            Return CInt(Me.DefaultDevice.AudioEndpointVolume.MasterVolumeLevelScalar * 100I)
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            Me.DefaultDevice.AudioEndpointVolume.MasterVolumeLevelScalar = CSng(value / 100I)
        End Set
    End Property

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Mutes the volume.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Sub Mute()
        Me.DefaultDevice.AudioEndpointVolume.Mute = True
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Unmutes the volume.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Sub Unmute()
        Me.DefaultDevice.AudioEndpointVolume.Mute = False
    End Sub

End Class
```

Example Usage:

```
Private Sub Test() Handles MyBase.Shown

    Dim MasterVolume As New MasterVolume

    With MasterVolume

        ' Mutes the device.
        .Mute()

        ' Unmutes the device.
        .Unmute()

        ' Set device volume at 50%
        .Volume = 50I

        ' Shows the current device volume.
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Current Vol.: {0}%", .Volume()))

    End With

End Sub
```